# Google Business Profile API - Pub/Sub Notification - Review reply

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-business-profile-api

I've implemented a Pub/Sub subscription to get notified when a new review is published on Google Business Profile. I have followed [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup).

When a new review is published, I'm getting a NEW_REVIEW notification. When a review is updated, I'm getting a UPDATED_REVIEW notification.

But, I'm not getting UPDATED_REVIEW notification when a Google Business Profile owner replied to a review.

There is another thing to implement or to subscribe to be notified when a owner is replying to a review ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any information on how to get notified when a Google Business Profile owner replied to a review. It seems that this feature is not available yet.